# Adding a new account in Team Foundation Server

Tags: tfs

I have a problem with adding of new accounts into Team Foundation Server 2010. I can add a new domain account into group Contributors of my team project without problems but after that I can't see it in the list of available accounts, for example, in the drop down list 'Assigned To' at a work item page.
The added user can see the project, do check-in and check-out but he can't get access to the project work items. He has got an error

TF201072: A user or group could not be found. Verify that the users and groups used in your work item type definition have been added to Team Foundation Server.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: You are likely hitting a bug. As TFS 2010 drops out of mainstream support in a few months you should upgrade to TFS 2013 and i believe your issue will be magiced away...

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure that you have the latest version of TFS. There have been many bugs fixed over the years and years since 2010 and you would be best servers to upgrade.

You should check the status of the TFS jobs, with the tfs Admin Pack:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/granth/archive/2010/07/12/administrative-report-pack-for-team-foundation-server-2010.aspx

Comment: I have tried to run these reports but I suspect that I have some wrong version. I don't have database 'Tfs_Warehouse' and several objects referenced in the report's data sources (DimTeamProject etc.).

Answer (score 0):

Is that user licenced?
we've got a tfs_member AD group which we've added in here:
http://yourtfs:8080/tfs/_admin/_licenses
to sort that out. The user has to be in that AD group and be in the project's contributors to show up .

Comment: Yes, it is licensed. Unfortunately, we don't have on our TFS site the link [http://yourtfs:8080/tfs/_admin/_licenses](http://yourtfs:8080/tfs/_admin/_licenses).
Is our version obsolete?

Comment: re: link my fault, I hadn't spotted you were using a tfs2010 installation, and it's related to TFS Web Access.